# AVPlayer libBacktraceRecording.dylib macOS App Crash

Tags: swift, macos, video-streaming, avplayer

I'm currently developing a macOS application and I get a strange error from time to time. I use AVPlayer to stream a live video. Everything works fine but after some time of streaming suddenly the app crashed with the following error:

```
libBacktraceRecording.dylib`__gcd_queue_item_enqueue_hook_block_invoke:
    0x10019fe32 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x10019fe33 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
->  0x10019fe36 <+4>:  movq   0x20(%rsi), %rax
    0x10019fe3a <+8>:  movq   0x20(%rdi), %rcx
    0x10019fe3e <+12>: cmpq   0x8(%rcx), %rax
    0x10019fe42 <+16>: sete   %al
    0x10019fe45 <+19>: popq   %rbp
    0x10019fe46 <+20>: retq
```

And the message in the console log looks like this:

```
2017-05-02 14:02:36.909336+0200 SampleApp[3460:236302] sendMessageWithCategory: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd}
2017-05-02 14:02:36.909421+0200 SampleApp[3460:236302] initWithSessionInfo: XPC connection interrupted
2017-05-02 14:02:36.909548+0200 SampleApp[3460:236302] sendMessageWithCategory: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd}
(lldb)
```

Comment: Facing the same console messages. Would be great if somebody could shed some light on this.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with App Transport Security. But I am not sure. Well, guess I'll raise my first bounty. Has to be a first for everything..

Comment: Hmm ok, so the failing connection to `com.apple.rtcreportind` seems to be [directly related](https://www.onemorething.nl/community/topic/pancake-apple-com/) to Apple's `Real Time Clock Reporting Deamon`. Still not a clue as to why this is failing, just putting it out there hoping it will ring a bell for someone..

Comment: @user2403221 Can you please add the code which are using . So that will able to check what is the problem aslo i think this crash is because of observer.

Comment: Is this happening on the simulator or also on a real device?

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza: I would imagine since it's macOS that's it's a real device.

Comment: Ops!! I missed that info. Sorry!!

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza any answers to this yet I am getting same errors  --- see my question on SO -- AVPlayer won't let me access URL